# GWT Dynamic String Internationalization

Tags: gwt, internationalization

Can someone explain how to use this feature. i'm trying to search for an example on the web but not getting it. Also, if at run time, the user wants to change language, how to do so??

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#LocaleSpecifying), you can

- either specify "locale" GET parameter in your URL, for example:

  http://www.domain.com/application.html?locale=fr_CA
- or add meta tag to your host HTML page, for example:

You may find complete internationalization example [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/aef26afdb2b35372/438794aa89cf246c?lnk=gst&q=%09GWT+Internationalization+Example#438794aa89cf246c) - it uses locale get parameter approach.

As far as I understand, there's no way to change localization without GWT module re-loading (see [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#LocaleProperty) for details).

Answer (score 0):

Both these approaches are static. But for the dynamic approach, this is very hard. Based on the current user's locale, change the ui rendering is NOT that easy...

If any